# Why do the files in gitignore keep getting pushed?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, github, gitignore

[image]

I have added the files to gitignore but they keep getting pushed. Now I have even deleted this file but I keep getting this error. I've tried refreshing the git cache, still the error persists.

Comment: Once a file is in the repo, gitignore doesn't apply to it until it's deleted. Try https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-files/deleting-files-in-a-repository and https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository

Comment: @Martheen Actually I have deleted the file. Still the error is showing.

Comment: From the repo too? Try pulling first.

Comment: @Martheen Yes I tried that still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Change the /node_modules to node_modules in your .gitignore file.
As node_modules folder is very large file, you don't want to push it github.

Comment: Actually the node modules is not getting pushed. A file "data.mdb" keeps getting pushed on its own even when I have deleted that file.

Answer (score 0):

There are several stages that have to be fixed, and not very easy for the begginer.

Going from not really the right side:

0. As Anandateertha notes, you might want to change the /node_modules to node_modules. (However this is not necessary because the meaning of `/` in .gitignore is different.)
1. `.gitignore` does not remove the file from the repo, it applies only to file not in repo. If you added the files before, you need to remove them from the (local) repo by something like `git rm <FILE_YOU_WANT_TO_LOOSE>` or `git rm --cached <FILE_TO_REMOVE_FROM_REPO>` followed by `git commit`
2. `git push` does not push your tree (your real files) (and does not reflect .gitignore), but it pushes the current state of your local repository.
   May be you should consider to undo one or a few local commits before doing git push again.

Solution 1.  some `git reset ...` + carreful git add && git commit + push again

Solution 2. (I doubt this would work because `push` might push the history together with the top)  `git rm --cached .parcel-cache/data.mdb` + `git commit` + `git push`

Maybe start by looking at `git log --stat` and (of course) `git status`.

Comment: Actually I have tried git rm --cached thing but doing just git rm gives me

fatal: /.parcel-cache: '/.parcel-cache' is outside repository at 'D:/JS prac/reactapp'

Comment: slash `/` at the start means root directory. Root directory is outside of our tree. Therefor `git rm --cached /whatever` must say `/whatever` is outside. Try no slash `.parcel-cache` or `./.parcel-cache`. And show us please the first 14 lines of `git log --stat`.

Comment: Tried both, it says

fatal: pathspec '.parcel-cache' did not match any files

Comment: Git stat

commit 5caf9d8fe88b923d063e84145ecaf06d762b6690 (HEAD -> main)
Merge: b791f81 6fbf57f
Author: name email>
Date:   Sat Aug 19 13:07:32 2023 +0530

    Merge branch 'main' of https://github.com/<url>

commit 6fbf57f29927dc71e3ee97b1e7e26d713f4fc8ea (origin/main)
Author: Name <102302265+Gitusername@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Sat Aug 19 13:07:26 2023 +0530

    Delete .parcel-cache directory

Comment: OK, the second commit `6fbf57f` is currently HEAD (=top) on github. The first commit seems to be merge of  github to your local repository. I think you can repeat that later, so I would remove that last part by `git reset HEAD^`. What does `git log --stat` say then. What does `git status` say?